OpenCV Imports Not Recognized in Eclipse Java Project
I'm on the latest version of Windows trying to set up a very simple program using OpenCV with Java in Eclipse, but I’m running into issues with the OpenCV imports. I have all the necessary software, including the latest versions of JDK, OpenCV (4.1.0), and Eclipse. I’ve created a new Java project in Eclipse, but when I try to import OpenCV classes like:
import org.opencv.core.Core;

I get the following error:
"The type org.opencv.core.Core is not accessible."
Here is my current set up:
package test; 

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

public class OpenCVTest {
    static { System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mat matrix = new Mat(3, 3, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + matrix);
    }
}

It's a very beginner basic program, as im just trying to get the compatibility aspect down first. Despite this setup, the import issue persists. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on what might be going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Checked the Build Path:
Added opencv-4100.jar to the classpath in Eclipse.
Set Native Library Location:
Set the native library location to the x64 folder with the DLL files (64-bit system).
Verified Version Compatibility:
Ensured the JAR (opencv-4100.jar) and DLLs (opencv_core410.dll) match for OpenCV 4.1.0.
Tried to Import OpenCV Classes:
Tried importing org.opencv.core.Core, but Eclipse still shows "The type org.opencv.core.Core is not accessible."
What I Expected:
The OpenCV imports to work without errors.
What Actually Happened:
Eclipse still shows the "not accessible" error.
SOLVED: Removed the 'module-info.java' that was automatically created when making the Java project.

Wrap your code snippets inside three back-ticks. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Have a module-info.java file present but don't care about Java's modularization system? Delete it, because it's one of the main causes of this message.
